# How faster Int comparison is than ByteString comparison in Haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell, comparison, bytestring

I'm implementing patterns mining algorithm, and usually input data are file with the following format

```
item1 item2 item3
item0 item3 item10
....
item30 item40 item30
```

where usually `itemx` is a `String`. To be efficient, I used to read the file with `ByteString` which is faster than the default `String`. Since the great task in patterns mining algorithms is comparison between items sets. I wonder How faster or slower my program will be if I change the input file format in order to make comparison between `Int` instead of comparison between `ByteString`. Here is the novel format :

```
1 2 3
0 3 10
....
30 40 30
```

thanks !

Comment: are you familiar with the excellent [criterion library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion)? I would suggest doing a few quick benchmarks that represent your use case and answer your own question

Comment: Or better yet, don't use a text-based file format at all and just store sets of X bit words, how ever small you can make them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you restrict yourself to just asking whether the equality function on Int - given by the `eqInt#` primop - is faster than the equality function on bytestrings -

```
primop   IntEqOp  "==#"   Compare
   Int# -> Int# -> Bool
   with commutable = True
```

vs

```
eq :: ByteString -> ByteString -> Bool
eq a@(PS fp off len) b@(PS fp' off' len')
  | len /= len'              = False    -- short cut on length
  | fp == fp' && off == off' = True     -- short cut for the same string
  | otherwise                = compareBytes a b == EQ
{-# INLINE eq #-}
```

Then the Int case will be faster. No doubt.

However, if you have to parse your bytestring input (or String input) into `Int` tokens first, you might lose.

The only way to really know here is to measure.